# Phonegap Javascript OO, this reference

Tags: javascript, android, oop, cordova

I'm trying to use OO with PhoneGap and I noticed that I can't use the "this" reference to the object inside his own methods.

Ex.:

```
var App = function() {
    this.a = function() {
        return true;
    }

    this.b = function() {
        alert(this.a());
    }
}
```

In App.b() when I run on a browser it works fine, but as a phonegap app (android) doesn't. Does anyone knows why?

I solved this with:

```
var App = function() {
    var self = this;

    this.a = function() {
        return true;
    }

    this.b = function() {
        alert(self.a());
    }
}
```

And call it

```
var app = new App();
app.b();
```

But it looks like not a good practice.

Thanks.

Comment: What is supposed for you to be `this` in `App.b()` ? Aren't you missing a `new` ?

Comment: Yes, I call like, var app = new App(), and then, app.b(). The problem is that this works fine on the browser, but when tested as an android app it does nothing.

Comment: The code you show in your question is very different from your comment.

Comment: Just @dystroy says, your code doesn't have any `new`, your code should work if you use it.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I cut part of the code and it became ambiguous. I edited the code to be more complete.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the code you are looking for is:

```
var App = {
    a: function() {
        return true;
    },
    b: function() {
        alert(this.a);
    }
}
```

---

**EDIT**

If you want instantiation, then do this:

```
function App() {}
App.prototype = {
    a: function() {
        return true;
    },
    b: function() {
        alert(this.a);
    }
}
var app1 = new App(),
    app2 = new App()

app2.a() // true
```

Comment: I'm trying to use it as a class. Unfortunately, this way I can't instantiate more than one App object.